# Quiero detectar las veces que se abre la app o bien que haya pasado N dias de su instalación para mostrar valoración de la app en swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Necesito obtener cuantas veces se ha abierto la app en swiftUI para así a 5 aperturas lanzar el diálogo de valoración de la app

O bien que tras la instalación haya pasado N días para lanzarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El final he econtrado un repositorio

https://github.com/mezhevikin/AppReview

He modificado la parte `isNeeded`para que tenga en cuenta, si llega a N aperturas o N días de la primera vez que se abre, como extra que si hace 90 dias de que el usuario valoró o no la app, se le pida de nuevo.

*Tener en cuenta que Apple solo muestra el diálogo de valorar la app 3 veces entre 365 dias*

Como caréncia no he encontrado la forma de controlar si el usuario a valorado la app o a decidido cancelar el diálogo.

```swift
import Foundation
import StoreKit

public class AppReviewManager {
    
    private let minLaunches: Int
    private let minDays: Int

    public init(minLaunches: Int = 10, minDays: Int = 7) {
        print("init")
        self.minLaunches = minLaunches
        self.minDays = minDays
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    public static func requestIf(launches: Int = 10, days: Int = 7) -> Bool {
        AppReviewManager(minLaunches: launches, minDays: days).requestIfNeeded()
    }
    
    private let ud = UserDefaults.standard
    
    private var launches: Int {
        get { ud.integer(forKey: "AppReviewLaunches") }
        set(value) { ud.set(value, forKey: "AppReviewLaunches") }
    }
    
    private var firstLaunchDate: Date? {
        get { ud.object(forKey: "AppReviewFirstLaunchDate") as? Date }
        set(value) { ud.set(value, forKey: "AppReviewFirstLaunchDate") }
    }
    
    private var lastReviewDate: Date? {
        get { ud.object(forKey: "AppReviewLastReviewDate") as? Date }
        set(value) { ud.set(value, forKey: "AppReviewLastReviewDate") }
    }
    
    private var lastReviewVersion: String? {
        get { ud.string(forKey: "AppReviewLastReviewVersion") }
        set(value) { ud.set(value, forKey: "AppReviewLastReviewVersion") }
    }
    
    private var daysAfterFirstLaunch: Int {
        if let date = firstLaunchDate {
            return daysBetween(date, Date())
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    private var daysAfterLastReview: Int {
        if let date = lastReviewDate {
            return daysBetween(date, Date())
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    private var isNeeded: Bool {
        if lastReviewVersion == version {
            let hasMetLastReviewDateCondition = lastReviewDate == nil || daysAfterLastReview >= 90
            return hasMetLastReviewDateCondition
        }
        
        let hasMetLaunchesCondition = launches >= minLaunches
        let hasMetDaysCondition = daysAfterFirstLaunch >= minDays
        
        return hasMetLaunchesCondition || hasMetDaysCondition
    }

    @discardableResult
    public func requestIfNeeded() -> Bool {
        if firstLaunchDate == nil { firstLaunchDate = Date() }
        launches += 1
        
        print("requestIfNeeded \(isNeeded)")
        print("launchers \(launches)")
        print("daysAfterFirstLaunch \(daysAfterFirstLaunch)")
        print("lastReviewDate \(lastReviewDate as Date? ?? Date())")
        print("version \(lastReviewVersion ?? "N/A")")

        guard isNeeded else { return false }
        
        lastReviewDate = Date()
        lastReviewVersion = version
        
        request()

        return true
    }
    
    private func request() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            #if os(iOS)
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
                    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
                }
            } else {
                SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
            }
            #else
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
            #endif
        }
    }
    
    internal var version = Bundle.main.object(
        forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString"
    ) as! String
    
    internal func daysBetween(_ start: Date, _ end: Date) -> Int {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: start, to: end).day!
    }
    
}
```

Su uso

```swift
AppReviewManager.requestIf(launches: 5, days: 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay una publicación de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966810/count-number-of-times-app-has-been-launched-using-swift) que indica usar el método que proviene de `UserDefaults`, [synchronize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize).

```
// obtener las veces que la aplicación se ha lanzado
let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCount")

// incrementar el valor devuelto por 1
UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCount+1, forKey:"launchCount")
```

Para la cuenta de los días desde su instalación no existe una interfaz especifica para esta tarea entonces puedes implementar una lógica que sea algo como esto ya iniciado **`UserDefaults`**.

`NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(savedDate)`

Dialogo de valoración

```
import StoreKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview

    var body: some View {
        Button("Review the app") {
            requestReview()
        }
    }
}
```